# ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder

Tags: java, keycloak

trying to create a keycloak object to register new user with keycloak with following code:

```
 Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                            .realm(realm)
                            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                            .clientId(clientId)
                            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                            .username("someone")
                            .password("someword")
                            .build();
```

But get following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder] with root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
>           at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.(Keycloak.java:58) ~[keycloak-admin-client-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>           at org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder.build(KeycloakBuilder.java:147)
>   ~[keycloak-admin-client-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>           at hello.GreetingController.greeting(GreetingController.java:100)
>   ~[main/:na]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

Comment: Are you using maven to add keycloak dependency or directly including keycloak jar in classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to add these dependencies to your project pom. 
Versions of dependencies could be 3.6.0.Final or 3.5.0.Final (i am not sure your keycloak-admin-client dependency version. But, i used keycloak-admin-client 3.0.0.Final with 3.5.0.Final resteasy-client. It works successfully.)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced such issue, try to exclude overrides packages, ex:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```